# Bootstrap-5 "Texto Responsivo<p></p>"

Tags: bootstrap-5

Estaba tratando de dejar un contenedor con una fila y dos columnas para poder generar una división como se ve entre  los colores negro y esmeralda , la idea es que del lado izquierdo quede una imagen(cuadrada) con el mail por debajo de la imagen y del lado derecho quede un texto explicativo , la dificultad que me encontré es que mi texto no se esta acomodando al cambio de pantalla , pensé que se iba a adaptar directamente al cambio junto con el contenedor

Ejemplo Mínimo verificable
https://github.com/Batvizz/EjemploProblema

```
        <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mt-5 "id="categoria1">About me</h2>
        <div class="divider-custom">
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="container-fluid bg-warning" id="about" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm bg-secondary">
    
                    <img class="img-responsive" class="ms-5" src="imagenes/omoiavatar.png" alt="png" />
                    <a href="mailto:info@domain.com"><p class="px-5">bygmail.com</p></a>
        
                </div>
                <div class="col-md bg-primary">
                        
                       <p>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdñlfkgjdslkfgjdlskfgjdslñkfgjlsñdkfgjldñskfgjdlsñkfgjdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p>
                       <p>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdñlfkgjdslkfgjdlskfgjdslñkfgjlsñdkfgjldñskfgjdlsñkfgjdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p> 
                       <p>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdñlfkgjdslkfgjdlskfgjdslñkfgjlsñdkfgjldñskfgjdlsñkfgjdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p> 
                       <p>sdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdñlfkgjdslkfgjdlskfgjdslñkfgjlsñdkfgjldñskfgjdlsñkfgjdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p>  
                            
          
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
```

Algunas imágenes para que se puedan guiar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Adjunto el link del repositorio para que puedas ver el HTML completo :) Link del repositorio :https://github.com/Batvizz/Portfolio

Comment: okey gracias Excorpion , ahora me voy a informar y voy a armar el ejemplo mínimo verificable

Comment: https://github.com/Batvizz/EjemploProblema , acabo de crear un ejemplo que se puede ejecutar

Comment: Bien !! ahora edita la publicación y agregalo acá ;)

Comment: El ejemplo mínimo verificable está bien echo y redactado. No se podrá agregar ejemplos de CSS porque se trata de bootstrap (ya está creado y listo para su uso sin errores), entonces el problemas está en el HTML5 y el agregar sus clases; lo cual ya está en la pregunta

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz el MVCE no está ni no existe en la pregunta. Y sí, se puede agregar el CSS con la etiqueta `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` y usar los CDNs propios de Bootstrap para poder reproducirse dentro de SOes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He modificado tú código.

Para la columna que contienen la imagen utilizar class="col-md-4" y para el texto class="col-md-8".

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

   <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mt-5 "id="categoria1">About me</h2>
        <div class="divider-custom">
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
            <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
        </div>


        <div class=" container-fluid bg-warning" id="about" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 bg-secondary ">
    
                    <img style="height:100px;width: 100%; max-width: 200px; min-height: 30px; height: auto;" class="img-responsive" class="ms-5" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="png" />
                    <a href="mailto:info@domain.com"><p class="px-5">bygmail.com</p></a>
        
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                       <p>sdasdasdasdasdasdasda sdasdasdasdasdasdasdassdñlfkgj dslkfgjd lskfgjdslñkfgjlsñd kfgjldñskfgjdlsñkfgj dasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p>
                       <p>sdasdas dasdasdasdasdasdasda sdasdasdasdasdassdñl fkgjdslkfgjdlskfgjdslñkfg jlsñdkf gjldñskf gjdlsñkfgjdasdas dasdasdasdasdasd</p> 

          
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>    

</div>
```

Comment: SI era la ida que estaba intentando lograr , gracias elierick

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte amigo @Batvizz

Answer (score 0):

El contenedor debe tener `p-3`, y para agrupar al centro `text-center`:

```
<div class="col-md bg-primary p-3 text-center"> </div>
```

A tus párrafos ponle la clase lead:

```
<p class="lead"></p>
```

Comment: intente con esos cambios narciso pero no funciono

Comment: gracias narciso capo 4

Comment: Es que a mí me funciona muy bien. Por su puesto, con ese texto sin espacio no funciona. De lo contrario, agregale a tu párrafo ```style="display: block; white-space: nowrap;"```